# SwipeNavigationController framework from GitHub how to implement

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, snapchat

so my question today is how can I add a view similar to Snapchat where you use gestures to swipe to other views: left, top, bottom, right. I'm trying to use this [framework](https://github.com/Lomotif/swipe-navigation) but I'm not sure how to really implement it as they haven't provided a sample project. The layout of my app is I have a signup/login view controller, from there I want it to go to another view (blue) and that's the view that I want to have the different gestures mentioned above. `import UIKit
import SwipeNavigationController

```
class BlueViewController: UIViewController {


let orangeVC = OrangeView()

let pinkVC = PinkView()
let greenVC = GreenView()
let purpleVC = PurpleView()



override func viewDidLoad() {



    let swipeNavigationController = SwipeNavigationController(centerViewController: self)
    swipeNavigationController.topViewController = self.pinkVC
    swipeNavigationController.bottomViewController = self.purpleVC
    swipeNavigationController.leftViewController = self.greenVC
    swipeNavigationController.rightViewController = self.orangeVC





    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.facebookBlueColor
   }
}'
```

I'm also not using storyboards for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SwipeNavigationController` is a `UIViewController` and can be pushed onto a stack or presented the same as any other `UIViewController`. Wherever you are creating and presenting `BlueViewController`, you should instead create the `SwipeNavigationController` as the top level object that contains `BlueViewController` and all of the direction view controllers. `BlueViewController` and all of the other directions should not know anything about the `SwipeViewController`. `BlueViewController` and all of the other directions should not know anything about each other. The `SwipeNavigationController` is the top level view controller, all of the view controllers associated with a direction are child view controllers of it. I'm assuming that you have a navigation controller somewhere in your flow that pushes the `SwipeNavigationController`. In that case, you would have something like this in whatever method you want to trigger the push. I've called it `nextTapped`, but I'm sure it'll be something different in your code:

```
func nextTapped() {
    let swipeNavigationController = SwipeNavigationController(centerViewController: BlueViewController())
    swipeNavigationController.topViewController = PinkViewController()
    swipeNavigationController.bottomViewController = PurpleViewController()
    swipeNavigationController.leftViewController = GreenViewController()
    swipeNavigationController.rightViewController = OrangeViewController()

    navigationController?.pushViewController(swipeNavigationController, animated: true)
}
```

And then remove everything from `viewDidLoad` in `BlueViewController` except for the line that sets the background color. This creates the `SwipeNavigationController` with all of the directional view controllers, keeping the `BlueViewController` as the center and then pushes it onto your view controller stack. If you don't have a `UINavigationController` in the view controller that is displayed before the SwipeNavigationController, you can present it modally by replacing the last line with this:

```
present(swipeNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Ok but how can I add it as the root view controller if I have a SplashScreen that's the root view controller, then from there I reset the root view controller to a navigation controller with the Signup/Login view controller, and if the user has already signed in previously, it present the BlueViewController. How do I go about that? Thanks!

Comment: @Jaqueline I was just guessing on your architecture. Keep the splash screen as your root view controller in the AppDelegate. In your SplashScreen, create the swipeNavigationController as shown above and push it onto the stack however you were transitioning to BlueViewController. SwipeNavigationController inherits from UIViewController, you can present it modally or push it with a navigation controller. Use it however you would use any other view controller.

Comment: @Jaqueline I've updated the code above to be more generic and not reference the App Delegate. Basically, use the SwipeNavigationController the same way you would use any other UIViewController, after you've created it with a view controller for each direction.

Comment: Thank you for that it looks like it would work perfectly! In the meantime I decided to do this another by making a custom present to the other views so they present from the right and left etc. It seems to work perfectly but do you think that would cause any problems in the future?

Comment: @Jaqueline I couldn't tell you, that depends on how you implemented it.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! I was able to successfully implement it. However one thing that isn't working correctly is on the BlueVC, it's actually a camera view created with the framework SwiftyCam  and for some reason you can't swipe to the other views in the middle of the screen, only the bottom where the buttons to the next view are. Do you know of a way to make it work as expected?

Comment: @Jaqueline Sounds like the touch events are getting intercepted by the camera. I would recommend posting that as a separate question, it's outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you I already figured it out. In the framework there was a pan gesture to zoom but I just wanted the pinch to zoom and so I went in and deleted the gesture so that it wouldn't sense it anymore blocking out the one I needed and now it works as it should. Thanks for all your help!